# Loading a JTable without losing sync

Tags: java, swing, synchronization, jtable, repaint

This example features a `JDViewCustomer` dialog which has two buttons`<` and `>` to reload a `JTable` asynchronously (I've added a few `Thread.sleep()` calls to simulate a network load).

Pressing the buttons quickly causes the application to lose sync with the screen (see class `LoadCustomerOrdersWorker.java` which also performs the revalidate/repaint after the data has been loaded).

How can I prevent that from happening?

**Test.java**

```
package testrepaint;

public class Test {

    private static JFrame frame;

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        run();

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void run() {

        List<CustomerOrder> customerOrders = new ArrayList<>();
        customerOrders.add(new CustomerOrder(15, 60.0f));
        customerOrders.add(new CustomerOrder(16, 280.0f));
        customerOrders.add(new CustomerOrder(17, 150.53f));
        customerOrders.add(new CustomerOrder(18, 280.0f));

        new JDViewCustomer(frame, true, customerOrders).setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**JDViewCustomer.java**

```
package testrepaint;

public class JDViewCustomer extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final ExecutorService SINGLE_THREAD_POOL = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    private JPanel jPanelCustomerOrders;
    private JPanel panelContainingTheOtherPanels;
    private JPanel panelAbaixoDeCustomerOrders;
    private JPanel panelContendoOsPedidos;

    private final List<CustomerOrder> customerOrders;
    private JPanel panelTituloPedidos;
    private JLabel lblPedidos;

    private JTable tableOrders;
    private JPanel panelPagination;
    private JButton btnPrevious;
    private JButton btnNext;
    private JLabel lblPageSelection;

    private int currentPage = 1;
    private int maxPage = 3;

    public JDViewCustomer(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal, List<CustomerOrder> customerOrders) {
        super(parent, modal);
        this.customerOrders = new ArrayList<>(Objects.requireNonNull(customerOrders));

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panelContainingTheOtherPanels = new JPanel();
        panelContainingTheOtherPanels.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelContainingTheOtherPanels, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        getContentPane().add(panelContainingTheOtherPanels);

        layoutCustomerOrdersSection();
        updateCustomerOrdersTable();

        updateCurrentPageTextField();
        toggleButtonsPreviousAndNext();

        initComponents();
    }

    private void layoutCustomerOrdersSection() {

        jPanelCustomerOrders = new JPanel();
        jPanelCustomerOrders.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        panelContainingTheOtherPanels.add(jPanelCustomerOrders);
        jPanelCustomerOrders.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanelCustomerOrders, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


        panelAbaixoDeCustomerOrders = new JPanel();
        panelAbaixoDeCustomerOrders.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));
        jPanelCustomerOrders.add(panelAbaixoDeCustomerOrders);
        panelAbaixoDeCustomerOrders.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelAbaixoDeCustomerOrders, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

                panelTituloPedidos = new JPanel();
                panelAbaixoDeCustomerOrders.add(panelTituloPedidos);
                panelTituloPedidos.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));
                panelTituloPedidos.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

                lblPedidos = new JLabel("Pedidos");
                panelTituloPedidos.add(lblPedidos);

        panelContendoOsPedidos = new JPanel();
        panelContendoOsPedidos.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
        panelContendoOsPedidos.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panelAbaixoDeCustomerOrders.add(panelContendoOsPedidos);
        panelContendoOsPedidos.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelContendoOsPedidos, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panelPagination = new JPanel();
        panelAbaixoDeCustomerOrders.add(panelPagination);

        addPaginationComponentsToPaginationPanel();
    }

    private void addPaginationComponentsToPaginationPanel() {
        btnPrevious = new JButton("<");
        btnPrevious.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                performButtonPrevious(e);
            }
        });
        btnPrevious.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        panelPagination.add(btnPrevious);

        lblPageSelection = new JLabel("0");
        panelPagination.add(lblPageSelection);

        btnNext = new JButton(">");
        btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                performButtonNext(e);
            }
        });
        btnNext.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        panelPagination.add(btnNext);
    }

    private void performButtonPrevious(ActionEvent e) {

        if (currentPage > 1) {
            currentPage -= 1;
            updateCurrentPageTextField();
        }

        toggleButtonsPreviousAndNext();

        loadCustomerOrders();
    }

    private void performButtonNext(ActionEvent e) {
        if (currentPage < maxPage) {
            currentPage += 1;
            updateCurrentPageTextField();
        }

       toggleButtonsPreviousAndNext();

       loadCustomerOrders();
    }

    private void loadCustomerOrders() {
        LoadCustomerOrdersWorker worker = new LoadCustomerOrdersWorker(customerOrders, this);
        SINGLE_THREAD_POOL.execute(worker);
    }

    private void toggleButtonsPreviousAndNext() {
        togglePreviousButton();
        toggleNextButton();
    }

    private void togglePreviousButton() {
        btnPrevious.setEnabled(currentPage > 1);
    }

    private void toggleNextButton() {
        btnNext.setEnabled(currentPage < maxPage);
    }

    private void updateCurrentPageTextField() {
        lblPageSelection.setText(String.valueOf(currentPage));
    }

    private void updateCustomerOrdersTable() {

        TableModel tableModel = instantiateAbstractTableModel();

        tableOrders = new JTable(tableModel) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return getPreferredSize();
            }            
        };

        centralizeTextInTableCells();

        //tableOrders.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        TableColumnModel colModel = tableOrders.getColumnModel();
        colModel.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(80);
        colModel.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(250);

        // Disables manual reordering of columns.
        tableOrders.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tableOrders);
        panelContendoOsPedidos.add(scrollPane);
    }

    private AbstractTableModel instantiateAbstractTableModel() {
        return new AbstractTableModel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return customerOrders.size();
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 5;
            }

            @Override
            public String getColumnName(int column) {
                switch(column) {
                case 0: return "Status";
                case 1: return "Número";
                case 4: return "Total";
                default: return "";
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                CustomerOrder customerOrder = customerOrders.get(rowIndex);
                switch(columnIndex) {
                case 0: return customerOrder;
                case 1: return "#" + String.valueOf(customerOrder.getNumber());
                case 4: return String.format("%.2f", customerOrder.getTotal());
                default: return "";
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                switch(columnIndex) {
                case 0: return CustomerOrder.class;
                case 1: return String.class;
                case 4: return String.class;
                default: return Object.class;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void centralizeTextInTableCells() {
        DefaultTableCellRenderer stringCellRenderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer)tableOrders.getDefaultRenderer(String.class);
        stringCellRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        tableOrders.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, stringCellRenderer);
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Ver Cliente");

        pack();

        // Para centralizar o JDialog em relação a seu parent.
        setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());

    }
}
```

**LoadCustomerOrdersWorker.java**

```
package testrepaint;

public class LoadCustomerOrdersWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    private final List<CustomerOrder> customerOrders;
    private final JDViewCustomer jDialogViewCustomer;

    public LoadCustomerOrdersWorker(List<CustomerOrder> customerOrders, JDViewCustomer jDialogViewCustomer) {
        this.customerOrders = customerOrders;
        this.jDialogViewCustomer = jDialogViewCustomer;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

        this.customerOrders.clear();
        Thread.sleep(300);
        this.customerOrders.add(new CustomerOrder(15, 60.0f));
        Thread.sleep(300);
        this.customerOrders.add(new CustomerOrder(16, 280.0f));
        Thread.sleep(300);
        this.customerOrders.add(new CustomerOrder(17, 150.53f));
        Thread.sleep(300);
        this.customerOrders.add(new CustomerOrder(18, 280.0f));
        Thread.sleep(300);
        this.customerOrders.add(new CustomerOrder(19, 280.0f));
        Thread.sleep(300);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        jDialogViewCustomer.revalidate();
        jDialogViewCustomer.repaint();
    }
}
```

**CustomerOrder.java**

```
package testrepaint;

public class CustomerOrder {

    private final int number;
    private final float total;


    public CustomerOrder(int number, float total) {
        this.number = number;
        this.total = total;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public float getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "toString()";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a LOT of code that not many people is willing to check. You have over 2K rep here and 10K+ in the PR site. You should know how to create a [mcve] that still reproduces your issue. Create a table with maybe 2-3 fields and if possible make all the variables / constants in English, remove colors / fonts / etc that is not needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You're right. I have reduced the classes. Please let me know if it is still too much code. The relevant point is that the application fails to revalidate / repaint the table properly, I'm not sure why. It looks like a synchronization issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic concept of updating a table is wrong:

1. The TableModel should contain the data structure. That is the ArrayList should be part of the TableModel. The TableModel should then have methods to modify the data dynamically.
2. the updates should be done to the TableModel. The TableModel will then notify the table to repaint itself.
3. See [Table Row Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step-by-step example on how to create a custom TableModel that incorporates the above suggestions.
4. Updates to Swing components (and their data) must be done on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. Code that executes in the doInBackground() method does NOT run on the EDIT. So instead of updating the ArrayList directly you need to `publish` the results and then updated the TableModel with the CustomOrder.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Tasks That Have Interim Results](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) for an example that shows how the `publish()` method works. Code executed in the `publish()` method DOES execute on the EDT.

5. There is no need to invoke revalidate() and repaint() in the done() method. As mentioned earlier, when you update the TableModel it will cause the table to be updated automatically.